# Why does Access keep reverting to the older version of linked SQL Server tables?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I'm having an issue with an Access database with linked back-end SQL Server tables. It seems that the tables are linked and working fine, yet when I exit and re-enter the database, I'm finding the tables are missing data, as if they've "reverted" to an old version. To fix this requires deleting and re-creating all the links (using the ODBC Machine Data Source). It only takes a couple of minutes, but why do you think this might be happening?

Comment: Most probably there is VBA code that links the tables to a **different** server or database on startup. Open a table in design mode and check its properties for the ODBC connect string.

Comment: Yep that was it!